# Is a compiler inline better than a manual inline?

Tags: inline, inline-assembly

I was told by a friend that compiler inline is better than the manual inline but he could not explain me why. What is the benefit of using the inline keyword if one can do it manually (except for writing same piece of code again and again)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Inline` works like a copy/paste controlled by the compiler, which is quite different from a pre-processor macro: The macro will be forcibly inlined, will pollute all the namespaces and code, won't be easily debuggable, and will be done even if the compiler would have ruled it as inefficient.

By marking it as `inline`, you can put a function definition in a header file (i.e. it can be included in multiple compilation unit, without the linker complaining).

Marking something `inline` does not give you a guarantee that it will be inline. It's just a suggestion to the compiler. Sometimes it's not possible such as when you have a virtual function, or when there is recursion involved. And sometimes the compiler just chooses not to use it.

Comment: Can you give some example where a macro would be ruled out as inefficient by the compiler(as mentioned in your first paragraph).

Comment: Macros are "inlined" before the compilation occurs, that is the sources are modified as per the macros, and then compiled.

Comment: If your inline code goes larger,it could provoke paging and defeat optimizations from the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

inline functions are useful when your function is called too frequently and small enough to fit in a cached memory...if compiler handles it, it can decide on using these parameters, however if you have more knowledge on target hardware, you can also do it manually..

Comment: So if the function is not used too frequntly & is not very large manual inline is equivalent to compiler inline ?

Comment: Manual inlining and auto inlining is same in performance manner..the only difference is compiler can do it for you and check all of your suitable functions, or you can do it by yourself if you know what you are doing and tell compiler to inline some critical and suitable functions.